# How can I query a MongoDB database with different child levels?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I'm new to mongoDB using pymongo. I'm trying to query a collection and also get a specific child from a field. This is what I tried:

```
import pymongo
import csv
from pymongo import MongoClient

connection = MongoClient()
db = connection.database
collection1 = db.data1
collection2 = db.data2
writer = csv.writer(open("Result_example.csv", "w"))
with open('Data_example.csv') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in spamreader:

        for rows in collection1.find({"_id": row[0]}, { "childs.first.name": 1}):
            writer.writerow([row[0], rows.get("childs.first.name")])
```

The database structure is like this:

```
child
   first
      name
```

What I want to get is the name...Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Other than the field not being pluralized in the example structure that was provided, the following query looks fine.

```
for rows in collection1.find({"_id": row[0]}, { "child.first.name": 1}):
```

**Note that** `child` field is singular.

`rows` is a reference to a dictionary object like below:

```
{
    'child': {
        'first': {
            'name': 'Vorname'
        }
    }
}
```

`rows.get("childs.first.name")` returns `None` in `writer.writerow([row[0], rows.get("childs.first.name")])`

You can retrieve the name using

> rows.get('child').get('first').get('name')

Or

> rows['child']['first']['name']

You can save these nested key accesses by running an aggregation that returns the *document id* and *firstname* in place of `collection1.find({"_id": row[0]}, { "child.first.name": 1})`.

```
children_names = db.collection1.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {'_id': ObjectId(row[0])}
    },
    {
        '$replaceRoot': {'newRoot': {'_id': '$_id', 'first_name': '$child.first.name' }}
    },

])
```

Key access could then be done once.

```
for rows in children_names:
    writer.writerow([row[0], rows.get("first_name")])
```